# why override prepareForSegue will show override can only be specified on class member

Tags: ios, swift, class, overriding

This is part of my code. I was trying to override prepareForSegue, so when I click a cell, it can into my another view controller and show different content based on  the cell I clicked . But I cannot override prepareForSegue.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class CategoryListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell:UITableViewCell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstrow", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "try"

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        switch segue.identifier {
        case .Some("DetailSegue"):
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController
            viewController.navigationItem.title = "Row \(indexPath.row)"

            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        default:
            super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
        }
    }



    return cell
}
}
```

Xcode tells me that `override can only be specified on class member`,but I need to `override prepareForSegue`. What's wrong with my code? This function can be override in my teacher's code, but it seems cannot be override in my code.

Comment: You've defined `prepareForSegue` inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Move it out and define it at the top level within your view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B CAREFUL MOVING CODE AROUND (Command Option "[" and "]"
because you can easily screw-up a curly bracket that way.
Hours can go by trying to figure out why your variable gets this error when all that was required was fixing an open or close bracket.

Spent 5 hours debugging on Saturday and it was a simple deletion of a bracket-- same error as here.